# How to solve "dimension mismatch"?

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension, mismatch

I get this message when running my programme:

> Error in metallror (line 23)
>       A(end,end-1)=(2.*r);      % byter ut den första elementen innan -(1/(2*h))

Is it something wrong with my `A`-matrix?

The program:

```
clc,clf,clear all

%Givet
Ti=450; r0=1;R=2;K=1;Te=20;
x=[1 2 4 8 ];    %används för att fördubbla våra intervall
g=0;               %fortsätt läs koden!
% N=4;               %Antal intervall
% n=N;
for i=1:4
    N=25*x(i);       %fördubblar delintervallena
    h=(R-r0)/N;      %steglängd
    r=r0+h:h:R;         %Inre punkter plus sista obekanta

    sub=(2*r-h)';    %'sub diagonal
    dia=(-4.*r)';       %'huvuddiagonal
    sup=(2*r+h)';   %'super diagonal


%vänsterled------
    A=spdiags([sub dia sup],-1:1,N,N);  % bildar en gles matris
    size(A)
    A(end,end-1)=(2.*r);      % byter ut den första elementen innan -(1/(2*h))
                                    % med vårt handberäknade värde
    A(end,end)=((-2.*r)-(2.*r.*h.*K)-((h.^2).*K));   % byter ut den sista elementen innan K

%högerled
    B=zeros(N,1);               % högerled
    B(1,1)=-Ti*((2*r0)-h);   % byter ut elementen med 
                                        % vårt handberäknade värde
    B(end,1)=((-2*h*K*r)*Te-((h.^2)*K)*Te);       % byter ut elementen innan KTe 

%Beräknar 
    U=A\B
    u=[Ti U']; %'

%visar resultatet
disp(['temperaturen vid r=2 med ',num2str(N),' delintervall är: ',num2str(u(end))])


%Ritar vår graf
    g=g+1;                  %används för att rita olika diagram
    subplot(2,2,g)
    size(r)
    size(u)
    plot([1 r],u),grid on       %[1 r],u)
    xlabel('Radie')
    ylabel('Temperatur')
    title(['Diagram med ',num2str(N),' delintervall' ])
end
```

Comment: Please make at least the effort to provide english comments. Welcome to Stackoverlflow though :)

Comment: You're assigning an array (`r`), to a single matrix entry in `A`. That won't fit of course. It's like trying to park all your 20 cars in a single garage box. And as JaBe said, not everyone here speaks Swedish, and SO is an English website. It would benefit your cause to provide English comments, since then everyone (and not just me and those few who speak Swedish) can understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of what it *seems* you try to do, you want to add some borders to your matrices. That is properly done like this:

```
A(:,end-1) =   2*r;
A(:,end)   = - 2*r - 2*h*K*r - h*h*K;
%// some more code
B(:,1) =          (- 2*h*K*r - h*h*K)*Te;
```

And, if you allow me to joke a bit: you must come from Lisp world, is quite a while since I saw so many abused parentheses. :-)